# blobstore images get_serving_url

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blobstore, attributeerror

I am new to the Google App Engine and I am trying to use the Blobstore to store images that I want to display later on.
The image storage works fine. Now I want to dynamically change some images in my html code. Therefore I need a method of getting the images out of the blobstore and passing them. I am using Python. I found the get_serving_url-command, which seemed to be the perfect fit. Sadly, this causes an Error and I seem to be unable to fix it.

My basic code looks like this:

> blob_key = "yu343mQ7kT4344N434ewQ=="
>
> ```
>   if blob_key:
>         blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)
>
>         if blob_info:
>             img = images.Image(blob_key=blob_key)
>             url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
>             ...
> ```

Everytime the function gets called, I get the following Error in my Log Console.

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py",
>   line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
>
> ```
> raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'ImagesNotImplementedServiceStub' object has no
>   attribute 'THREADSAFE'

I have no idea how to fix it or if I am doing something terribly wrong.

I am very grateful for your support! Thank you in advance!

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an instance of BlobKey so if you are getting blob_info successfully try:

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=blob_info.key())
url = images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key())
```

Comment: which blobstore did you import from?